# Would my mount be slowed if I wore medium/heavy armor?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor, mount

Does wearing medium or heavy armor reduce my mount's base land speed like my base land speed in Pathfinder?

Comment: To be clear, is the mount wearing medium or heavy armor *or* is the rider wearing medium or heavy armor ?

Comment: @HeyICanChan The title question does specify the character.

Comment: @RevenantBacon Yes, it does… and the question's body doesn't, which is why I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 5):

#### Mounts can be slowed by the rider's total weight.

The rider's armor itself does not slow down their mount. At least, not in the same way that wearing medium or heavy armor reduces a character's movement speed.

*However*, wearing medium or heavy armor adds weight to the rider.  If the total weight of the rider, their armor, their gear, saddle, barding, etc is all within the mount's light load capacity, then the mount can move at full speed with no problem.  But if this total weight is too much (and counts as a medium or heavy load), then you could overburden your mount past their carrying capacity.

Your mount's [carrying capacity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity/) is normally determined by their Strength score, size, and number of legs. To calculate, find the tables "Armor and Encumbrance for Other Base Speeds" and "Carry Capacity" (which are also in pages 170-171 in the *Core Rulebook*). Use these to determine your mount's light carry capacity, and the speed reduction caused by encumbrance.

For example, a [heavy horse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/horse/heavy-horse/) is large, quadrupedal, and has 20 Strength. Its light load capacity is 133 x 2 x 3 = 798 pounds. If the total weight of the rider (plus armor), barding, pack gear, and such is within 798 pounds, then the heavy horse takes no movement penalty.

Answer (score 4):

### It can, but not directly.

The armor you wear has no bearing on your mounts movement speed, *except* if you pass it's encumbrance limits with your weight (since it *is* carrying you).

For example, lets say you were a medium humanoid riding a large creature with a Str of 16. This gives them a carrying capacity of 152 or less for a light load, up to 306 for a medium load, and over that is heavy. If your character were wearing full plate (50lbs) and weighed more than 100 lbs himself (likely as a standard medium humanoid) that alone would push your mount into a medium load, reducing its speed accordingly. If your mount has a Str score of, say, 20, then its carry capacity would become 266 on a light load, which should be enough to cover full plate, plus the character (probably between 180-220 lbs combined) with enough capacity for other assorted gear, and still be in light load range.

Comment: Quadrupeds have a higher multiplier than normal creatures. This would give a large quadruped creature, with a strength score of 16, a light load of up to 228 lbs.

Comment: @Simon Right, but not all mounts are quadrupeds, like Axe Beaks for example.